# Mathematical expression of assignment case with vector

Tags: vectors

There is a vector $\pmb{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for which the smallest value is to be assigned to $v_{min} \in \mathbb{R}$. But if the smallest value is less than zero, then $v_{min} = 0$ applies.

This is my attempt to express it mathematically:

$v_{min} =
\begin{cases}
min\ \pmb{v}, & \text{if }\ \ \ \ \ \ min\ \pmb{v} \geq 0 \\
0, & \text{else} 
\end{cases}$

Are there alternative or more intuitive mathematical expressions?

Comment: Your definition is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:$$v_{min}=\max(0,\min{v_i}), v_i\in\mathbb R, i=\overline{1,n}$$In the end it's the same as your definition, just more compact